# Any way to integrate HTML snippets with django snippets?

Tags: html, django, visual-studio-code

I have two extensions installed one is Django (Baptiste Darthenay) and other is HTML Snippets (Mohamed Abusaid). By default every .html file was getting detecting as django-html and it had no intellisense so I changed the file.associations to following:
[image]

this has solved problem for html files which are not inside `**/tempaltes/**/*` but anything in side it doesnt have any intellisense at all.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tell Emmet (which is what's used for these snippets; details [here](https://docs.emmet.io/)) to use one language's snippets in another. To enable the `html` snippets in the `django-html` language, add the following to your VS Code settings (in the settings JSON editor):

```json
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
  "django-html": "html"
},
```

In the Settings UI mode, you can find this as **Emmet: Include Languages**. Click "Add Item", set "Key" to `django-html` and "Value" to `html`, then click "OK"